# What is the meaning of numRecords in a BatchInfo?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running Spark Streaming in local mode, pushing data into the stream by reading files from disk and pushing them into a SynchronizedQueue that belongs to a queueStream.

However, if I use a [StreamingListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener) to catch [BatchInfo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.BatchInfo)s and print the return value of the numRecords Method, it always comes out as 0.

I am confused by this because if I print the contents of my stream, using e.g. the print method, I see that the is not actually empty.

Example Output:

```
Number of Records: 0 //printed by the StreamingListener
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1468180140000 ms
-------------------------------------------
[D@2630210a
[D@2fff9ea2
[D@5b5153cd
[D@3854e691
[D@27185f49
[D@fb2b862
[D@1e6731fb
[D@7c4ab411
[D@25f701b
[D@47b8fdd4
...
```

Perhaps my understanding of what is meant by a "record" is wrong? Or could there be some bug that prevents this from working correctly in local mode or with queueStreams?